# Interfaces cannot ping each other over ovs vxlan

Tags: linux, networking, openvswitch

[image: network topology]

I'm setting up a layer 2 network over two virtual machines using OpenvSwitch-2.5.2, like the above picture shows.

After reading the ovs official tutorials and some other articles, I've tried the following cmds on each virtual machine:

```
# on vm1

ip link add dev veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip link add dev veth3 type veth peer name veth4
ip netns add ns0
ip netns add ns1
ip link set veth0 netns ns0
ip link set veth3 netns ns1
ip link set veth1 up
ip link set veth4 up
ip netns exec ns0 ip link set veth0 up
ip netns exec ns1 ip link set veth3 up
ip netns exec ns0 ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev veth0
ip netns exec ns1 ip addr add 10.0.0.3/24 dev veth3
ovs-vsctl add-br br0
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth1
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth4
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 vx1 -- set Interface vx1 type=vxlan options:remote_ip=192.168.99.101

# on vm2

ip link add dev veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip netns add ns0
ip link set veth0 netns ns0
ip link set veth1 up
ip netns exec ns0 ip link set veth0 up
ip netns exec ns0 ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev veth0
ovs-vsctl add-br br0
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 veth1
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 vx1 -- set Interface vx1 type=vxlan options:remote_ip=192.168.99.100
```

Turns out,

`#vm1 ip netns exec ns0 ping 10.0.0.2` failed.

Even worse,

`#vm1 ip netns exec ns0 ping 10.0.0.3` failed.

However, if I delete the vxlan port, on vm1, ping from veth0 to veth3 works well as expected.

Am I missing anything so that this whole overlay network just won't behave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by upgrading my kernel version from 3.13.x to 4.4.x.

Similar problem reported by another user is [here](https://mail.openvswitch.org/pipermail/ovs-discuss/2014-June/034151.html).